# Distribution chart using ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have got this kind of data frame (~7000 rows) :

```
> head (Distrib)
     Length     Number_of_occurences
          60                   12
          62                   52
          64                    1
          70                    3
          71                   12
          72                   82
```

I would like to get a distribution chart out of it with. So I am trying to get the values of the first column in the X-axis (but grouped in relevant intervals) and the second columns values in the Y axis.

I tried to use the parameter 'names' from `barplot()` but it doesn't work since I would like R to calculate frequencies of occurence and to make relevant intervals.

I also tried to use `hist()` but it doesn't work since every repetition is already counted in the second column.
I also tried ggplot from `ggplot2` :

```
ggplot(Distrib, aes(x=Length)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
```

But the result wasn't pretty, probably because the data frame has a lot of lines.

Comment: What's *relevant interval* and what's *grouping* (is it average of *Number_of_...*)?

Comment: I would like R to make Length classes such as '60-70', '71-80' ... , to sum the Number_of_occurences in each classes and then to plot the results in a distribution chart. If there is too many classes or too few classes it might be difficult to interpret such frequency distribution so I except R to find number of classes ?